# Convergence of summation operator on $L^2(\mathbb R)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis

I am trying to determine whether or not the following translation operator sends $L^2(\mathbb{R})\to L^2(\mathbb{R})$ Let:
$$ Tf(x): f\to\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}f(x-\log n)n^{-1/2}$$
Here is my work so far:

Let $g(x)=Tf(x)$. We want to see if $\int_\infty^\infty |g(x)|^2dx$ is finite or not for all $f\in L^2(\mathbb{R})$.

I believe the following inequalities are valid though i am not sure:
$$\int_\infty^\infty |g(x)|^2dx\leq \sum_n\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x-\log n)n^{-1/2}|^2dx$$
In the prior equation we express $\int_\infty^\infty |g(x)|^2dx$ as a summation over all individual translates with the $n^{-1/2}$ weight. (this becomes an equality for strictly positive or negative functions). I can't tell if the next set of inequalities hold or how to evaluate the final expression:

$$ \sum_n\int_{-\infty}^\infty|f(x-\log n)n^{-1/2}|^2dx< \int_{\log 1}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x-n)e^{-n/2}|^2 dxdn$$

any help is appreciated. thanks!

Comment: Intuitively, your operator $T$ should not map $L^2$ into itself because, roughly speaking, the squared norm of $Tf$ should "scale like"
$$\sum \|f_n n^{-1/2}\|^2 = \sum \|f\|^2/n = \infty $$
Where $f_n(x) =  f(x-\log n)$ has the same norm as $f$.

Answer (score 2):

The operator does not map $L^2$ to itself. A very simple counterexample is as follows. Define $f$ to be the following function:
\begin{align*}
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1 & \text{ if } x \in [0,1], \\ 0 & \text{ otherwise.} \end{cases}
\end{align*}

Clearly $f \in L^2$. Let us evaluate $Tf(x)$ for some fixed $x$. We have,
\begin{align*}
Tf(x) & = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} f(x - \log n) n^{-1/2} \\
& = \sum_{x-1 \leq \log n \leq x}  n^{-1/2} \\
& = \sum_{n = e^{x-1}}^{e^x}  n^{-1/2} \\
& \geq c (e^{x/2} - e^{(x-1)/2}) \\
& \geq c e^{x/2}(1- 1/2e).
\end{align*}

Here, $c$ is a universal constant. Since $e^{x/2} \notin L^2(\mathbb{R})$, neither is $Tf(x)$.